# How to add a slash at the end of category's url and remove it at the end of post's on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, categories, permalinks

How to make wordpress category's URL with slash at the end and without it in post's url. Like this:

"mysite.com/mycategory/" 
"mysite.com/mycategory/mypost"

The problem is that by default, you can either do everything with a slash or all without a slash.
('category' prefix already removed via htaccess).

Answer (score 2):

There are two good solutions for this:

The WP_Rewrite class has a var named `$use_trailing_slashes` that is set dynamically based upon whether or not your custom permalink structure ends in a '/'.

```
$this->use_trailing_slashes = ( '/' == substr($this->permalink_structure, -1, 1) );
```

This means that all WP generated links (the_permalink, category_link, the_permalink_rss, etc.) will not end in a '/'. So for category pages WP will show '/category/category' instead of '/category/category/'.

*You can solve it by either using a filter or modifying your .htaccess or both:*

**Sample user_trailingslashit Filter**

The user_trailingslashit function applies the 'user_trailingslashit' filter to the result prior to returning it. It provides the url and the type of url to the filter.

```
$string = apply_filters('user_trailingslashit', $string, $type_of_url);
```

So to hook into this and add a trailing slash to all urls other than single posts add this code to a plugin file or your functions.php theme file.

```
function fix_trailingsss($s='',$t='single')
{
  if($t!='single')$s=rtrim($s,'/').'/';
  return preg_replace('/^(.*)([^l/])$/i', '\1\2/',$s);
}
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'fix_trailingsss', 9999,2);
```

**Htaccess RedirectMatch**

You can setup an .htaccess redirect to force category urls to always use a trailing slash like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/([^/]+)$ /category/$1/
```

***Source of information***: https://www.askapache.com/wordpress/adding-trailing-permalinks/

For any further questions consult the codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_rewrite

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
function no_page_slash( $string, $type ){
    if($type == 'single')
        $string = untrailingslashit($string);
   return $string;
}
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'no_page_slash', 70, 2);
```

Your permalinks must be set on like /%category%/%postname%/ .